# how to specify the number of threads used by SBT during any command?

Tags: multithreading, scala, maven, sbt, dependency-resolution

Maven has the `-T <num_threads>` option. Is there anything similar for SBT? How can make it download my dependencies in parallel threads rather than doing it sequentially?

Comment: Not sure the exact thing you asked is possible. Here is what SBT docs suggest https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Parallel-Execution.html

Comment: thats seems like limiting tags for parallel execution. I am just trying to get the parallel execution to increase on my pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel dependency download has been supported since [SBT 1.0](https://developer.lightbend.com/blog/2017-08-11-sbt-1-0-0/#headline-features):

> sbt 1 by default uses Gigahorse HTTP client (backed by Square OkHttp)
>   to download artifacts in parallel.

This is also discussed in [Download artifacts in parallel #590](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/590)

[coursier](https://github.com/coursier/coursier) SBT plugin also supports downloading of dependencies in parallel:

> By default, downloads happen in a global fixed thread pool (with 6
>   threads, allowing for 6 parallel downloads), but you can supply your
>   own thread pool to `Cache.default`.